# Would "my dumb self" be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphens

When using the word "*self*" like this:

> "*My dumb self tripped over the rock,*"

would "*dumb*" and "*self*" be hyphenated?

Answer (score 2):

No. You are simply the subject and object of a prepositional phrase, and *dumb* is an adjective describing the object (*self*). It is entirely equivalent to:

> My expensive cell-phone exploded in my briefcase.

I've hyphenated *cell phone* for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

No, you would not hyphenate them, as "dumb" is simply an adjective clarifying the noun "self", no different than any other adjective-noun pair (i.e. "a tall mountain" or "a long walk").

The time to hyphenate two words is actually when you are creating a compound adjective by combining two or more words into an adjective. For example, in the phrase I wrote above ("adjective-noun pair"), the words "adjective" and "noun" are combined to create a compound adjective that clarifies the noun "pair". So using your sentence, you would use a hyphen if you wrote something like "my stone-dumb self tripped over the rock".

Hope that helps!